.NET Dapper SqlMapper slow query execution
In .NET 8 with Npgsql and Dapper, our query is incredibly slow compared to executing it directly through another database manager.
In our code, we execute queries as such:
var query = "select count(*) from mytable me where me.org_id = @orgId";

var result = await QueryAsync<int>(query, new { orgId, });
return result.Single();

The repository code that is called:
protected async Task<IEnumerable<T>> QueryAsync<T>(string query, object values)
{
    // These are fast
    await using var connection = await _postgresDataSource.OpenConnectionAsync(); // NpgsqlConnection
    await using var transaction = await connection.BeginTransactionAsync();
    await SetConfig(connection); // Runs "set role user;"

    // This is the slow part!
    return await connection.QueryAsync<T>(query, values, transaction, 
                                          commandType: CommandType.Text);
}

When running the exact same query in DBeaver / pgcli / psql, inside the transaction and with the same role, it executes in less than a second. In our application, it can take over 10 seconds.
Furthermore:

Removing the BeginTransactionAsync makes it fast. However, we require a transaction to perform Row Level Security, hence setting the role.
The Postgres database has plenty of resources available and has very low utilisation
The connection from the application is pooled (Pooling=true in connection string)

The query itself is optimised and with indexes, so it seems to be an issue in the application only.
What could be the cause of this slowness? How can we further debug this?
More info:
Npgsql: 8.0.3
Dapper: 2.1.44
PostgreSQL: 15.7


Does the data type of orgId match me.org_id in the database? Have you tried in DBeaver etc with Row Level Security as well? Maybe that's what's causing the issue.

If you just want a single int why do you let a micro ORM do it? The only thing dapper does is presumably model mapping and you don't need that here.

@Charlieface The orgId in C# is type string, and in the table, it is text. I assume those map.
And yes, in DBeaver and psql, I have tried setting the role and executing the query in a transaction -- exactly what the code should do.

@Ralf You're right that the ORM is a bit overkill here, but this issue happens in other queries with actual models too. This is just the smallest reproducible example

Is it possible for you to get the query plan for the slow version, eg by using pg_showplans https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/331263/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-where-a-query-currently-is-in-an-explain-in-postgresq

@Charlieface The query plan is the same, which I would also expect, since it is the exact same query. I did retrieve it by running explain analyze

explain analyze from DBeaver won't tell you the actual query plan being used from Dapper. The fact it's the same query doesn't mean you necessarily get the same plan, you need to use diagnostic tools to get the actual plan.

Hi @Janman, Investigate whether the transaction isolation level might be contributing to the delay. By default, Npgsql will use the ReadCommitted isolation level. Try specifying a less stringent isolation level (e.g., ReadUncommitted) await using var transaction = await connection.BeginTransactionAsync(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);

@Rena I did try using the ReadUncommitted, but that did not help either.
